# How can you configure axios running in jest to NOT send OPTIONS before POST?

Tags: axios, jestjs, http-toolkit

From node.js this works as expected, a POST response is sent (as I verified with httpToolkit)

```
% node
> const axios = require('axios')
> var r = (async () => { const x = await axios.post('http://example.com/v1/secret/data/foo/bar/baz',{data: {foo: 42}},{headers: {'X-Special-Token': 'DATA'}}); return true;})().then(console.log)
undefined
> true
```

But then doing the same from a `jest` test, `axios` is sending an OPTIONS request first.  The service I am running is not able to handle that (not example.com)

```
const axios = require('axios');

describe('Simple Post', () => {
  test('POST', async () => {
    // Axios HERE seems to send an OPTIONS request first...
    const x = await axios.post('http://example.com',
      {data: {foo: 42}},
      {headers: {'X-Special-Token': 'DATA'}});
    expect(x.status).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

Is there some way to convince/configure `jest` or `axios` so that `axios` does not magically decide to send `OPTIONS`?  *This has nothing to do with CORS* - its server code talking to server code, but obviously something in `axios` is deciding that it is appropriate.

Comment: wow, what a surprise! check the thread https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2654 and please-please compose an "official answer" if any advise here works to you.

Comment: Interestingly, I had read that and thought -- too much going on here.  And switched to `got` instead of `axios`, problem solved.  But I revisited, and it is "simple".

Comment: yeah, axios delegates to jest that delegates to jsdom and latter mimics browser's behavior and sends OPTIONS. Two many things happen.

Answer (score 5):

Reading through this [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2654) the solution to my problem is simply the header below.  See jest [test-environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string).  The issue does have much discussion about different concerns, so YMMV.

```
/**
 * This is required to prevent axios from acting like it is in a browser
 *   environment and doing OPTIONS preflights, etc.
 *
 * @jest-environment node
 */
const axios = require('axios');

describe('Simple Post', () => {
  test('POST', async () => {
    // No preflight OPTIONS request sent when jest-environment is node
    const x = await axios.post('http://example.com',
      {data: {foo: 42}},
      {headers: {'X-Special-Token': 'DATA'}});
    expect(x.status).toBe(200);
  });
});
```